# Deactivate a list of SKUs for a two specific websites?

Tags: magento2.3

How can I quickly deactivate a list of SKUs for a specific website?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of SKUs is comma separted I would suggest a SQL statement:

```
delete from catalog_product_website where website_id = YOURWEBSITEID ANd product_id IN (select entity_id from `catalog_category_entity` where sku in (sku1, sku2))
```

The Magento Backend does not provide a functionality to filter multiple products by their SKUs.

Comment: That leaves some dangling data, right?

Comment: well if you want to clean up unused data which was previously set on website or storeview level or url-rewrites or etc. you have to clean up more. so yes. this does leav dngling data

Comment: on the other side.... this might be some data you may want to keep....

Comment: sure, thanks a lot for the quick answer .. I opted for disabling this time, it seems more consistent :)

Comment: no worries! thanks for the discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this

```
# find out the store Ids for example with n98-magerun2 sys:store:list, in my case 9 + 10


select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code like "status" and entity_type_id = (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')

# note down the returned code, in my case 97

update  catalog_product_entity_int set value = 2 where attribute_id = 97 and (store_id = 9 or store_id = 10)
                                       and entity_id in (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity where sku in ("sku1","sku2", ....))
```

Comment: status is on website, not on storeview level. so in the rare case your website gets a new website this products could show up again!

Comment: Yeah that is strange, but I guess the website level status is still stored in `catalog_product_entity_int`, right? I am not talking about the website-assignment

Comment: yeah magento is kind of weird... if an attribute is set on website level it will actually store it for each storeview of the website